# Unable to reduce loss when doing sentiment analysis with Keras

Tags: machine-learning, python, keras

I created a model in Keras that predicts 4 sentiments/emotions based on text input. Size of my data:

```
label_1 : 100.000
label_2 : 100.000
label_3 : 100.000
label_4 : 50.000

Validation data: 45.000
```

I have set the class weights to: `class_weight = {'label_1':1, 'label_2':1, 'label_3':1, 'label_1':2}`

I have used `scikit-learn` for vectorising with `CountVectorizer`. For preprocessing, I have converted all to lowercase, removed emails, urls/links and removed stopwords.

```
This is my model:

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(50, input_dim = features.shape[1], activation = 'relu')) # input layer requires input_dim param
model.add(Dense(100, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(50, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(4, activation='softmax'))


opt = SGD(lr = 0.001, momentum = 0.01)
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer = opt, metrics=['accuracy'])

es = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta = 0.03, patience = 120, verbose=1, mode='auto')
history = model.fit(features, results, validation_split = 0.25, shuffle = True, class_weight = class_weight, epochs = 600, batch_size=512, verbose=2, callbacks=[es])

score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, batch_size=512)
print()
print(history.history.keys())
print()
print(score)
print('Test loss:', score[0],  'Test accuracy:', score[1])

Test loss: 0.215 Test accuracy: 0.900
```

These are the accuracy and loss graphs:

[image]

[image]

This is my prediction:

```
validation_features = transformerVectoriser.transform(validation_features)
prediction = model.predict_classes(validation_features , batch_size=512) # making prediction
```

These are confusion_matrix and accuracy_report:

```
[[11678   256  1181    23]
 [  477 12023   432    13]
 [ 1538   322 10947    18]
 [   16     9    17  6050]]


precision    recall  f1-score   support

0       0.85      0.89      0.87     13138
1       0.95      0.93      0.94     12945
2       0.87      0.85      0.86     12825
3       0.99      0.99      0.99      6092

accuracy                    0.90     45000
macro avg. 0.92   0.92      0.92     45000
weighted avg  0.91  0.90    0.90     45000
```

My question is, how can I reduce loss? I have tried to change number of layers, nodes and dropout layers, to change optimisers, learning rate and momentum, to change number of epochs and batch size, and to change max number of words (I have tried with 4.000, 5.000, 6.000, 8.000, 10.000, 12.000)

It does not matter what I change, my accuracy is always around 87%-90% (and I think thats good), but my loss is always around 0.21-0.24 (and I do not like that). On some data science related blogs I have read that loss should be less than 0.1. Is that true? What is acceptable loss value for multiclass classification?

Do you have any advices?

Answer (score 0):

There is no universal loss value result that you can or should achieve. Beside your model it will heavily depend on the data that you have.

What is good or bad result is subjective and depends on your use-case.

It's a very broad question how to improve the result of a neural network and you should be more specific but some ideas that can work generally:

1. Preprocess your data differently (i.e. use TF-IDF or use text as a sequence)
2. Collect more data (neural networks usually prefer that, also your test set seems small)
3. Use different optimizer (i.e. Adam)
4. Use different architecture (i.e. some RNN)
5. Use different algorithm (i.e. XGBoost)
6. Use BatchNormalization
7. Use some callback that modifies your learning rate
8. Tune your parameters